# How to suppres excel from office 365 when I have office 2013 installed?

Tags: excel, vba

We use Office 2013 and not Office 365. When starting excel from code, I get dialog boxes for Office 365 login etc. This stops my code.

Is it possible to start Excel Office 2013 from code?

```
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing

xlApp = New Excel.Application
```

Comment: From where do you want to start the Excel App, is it from a different Office App (Word, Outlook?)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing a `Set` statement for the xlApp as well as a `Dim` Statement if you have `Option Explicit` activated.
You do not need to declare the workbook as nothing when you Dim it... it will be nothing until you give it an object.

UPDATE:
I changed the code to check the version of Excel installed and only continue if it is Excel 2013

```
Sub test()

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook


Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Turn off notifications

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
'Only continue w/ code if it is version 15 (2013) else close app again
If xlApp.Version = 15 Then
    'Do stuff...
Else
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is not the code. The code is working but it starts the wrong excel. It starts the Office 365 excel and not the Office 2013 excel.

Comment: I don't know if it helps for your problem, but you definitively need the `Set`

Comment: I changed the code to reflect that you are looking for Excel 2013. Not sure if there is a way to test for the Excel Version without first starting the application.

Comment: Thank you! I will test it soon. But I am not sure if this will fix my probelm... I need to accsess the xlApp.Version 15...